# WebEngineWidgets doesn't work with MinGW compiler

Tags: qt, qml, mingw, qtwebengine

I've been working on a project, I want to add a video player for web videos.
I can't get qtwebenginewidgets work with MinGW compiler, I added QT += webenginewidgets to my profile, when I compile I have the following Error: *"Unknown module(s) in QT: webenginewidgets"* is there a **solution** for that **without changing compiler**, I searched but all I found is that I have to change compiler to MSVC 2017 or further.

Thank you.

Comment: You need MS compiler to build WebEngine, MinGW isn't supported. As I know it is Chromium limitation, not Qt.

Comment: But when i compile my program with MSVC compiler, i get 2 Errors  : < 'stddef.h'ÿ: No such file or directory> and < 'crtdbg.h'ÿ: No such file or directory>  It there a way to correct that without recreating the project ?

Comment: Check [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/91057/c1083-cannot-open-include-file-stddef-h-no-such-file-or-directory) thread

Comment: Thank you i will check this hope it will resolve the problem